# Jquery animate bug in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I use this code, but it's like the offset is never good. 
The goal of the offset:  my menu bar stay on top. So when i click on menu item it's scroll to top. minus the height of the menu. But  i always have a glitch that scroll again .

works fine in chrome but not in firefox an IE. is it clear?

```
 $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - menu.offsetHeight
     }, 300, function(){
       window.location.hash = hash;
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it.

It's not the scrollTop.

it's :

```
window.location.hash = hash;
```

In  IE and Chrome when assign a new value to hash property its scroll to it.

Answer (score 0):

> The `.animate()` method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric **CSS property**

So `scrollTop` is not CSS property, it's jQuery function. Change it to `margin-top`, `padding-top` or `top` if it's relative/absolute positioned element.

Comment: Hi , not working.  You can go  to http://jkdcq.ca/#horaire and try it in chrome and  IE. Click on menu see the diff. I want to fix IE

Comment: More info.  When i use margin-top or top or any, the smoothness of the scrolling disappear!